# Item Prediction from recommender system

Tags: python, numpy, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I have the similarity that I get from pairwise in python library for item based CF. Then I use this prediction from
[***Implementing your own recommender systems in Python***](https://cambridgespark.com/content/tutorials/implementing-your-own-recommender-systems-in-Python/index.html).

```
pred = ratings.dot(similarity) / np.array([np.abs(similarity).sum(axis=1)])
```

but I get bad rating prediction. The rating prediction are around 0.1 - 0.9. Is this pred calculation is valid?

Comment: What would you expect to get back? `0.1 - 0.9` looks like a normalized range, which should be just fine, but all your values will be between `0.01 and 0.99 (or 1)` depending on their match. Do you expect to get back larger numbers? (I wouldn't see any difference in recommendation performance though between a normalized and a non-normalized range).

Comment: I want get the predicted value in range 0-5. Is there possible way to convert that?

Comment: This is what i got from that prediction:                                                                                                     [0.11780604  0.12146975  0.118728   ...,  0.11945179  0.11526597
   0.11711326]

Comment: You can always frame your 0.1-0.9 range to 0-5 range: `(prediction - 0.1) * 6.25`

Comment: @zwer Thanks for your assistance, but after i use that equation i didnt get the value in range 0-5.                                                                                        

i found my data is in range is 0 - 0.2699459495. I need to change it to 0 - 5 for calculate correlation between rating predict with the truth table.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Thank you,I already got alternate for get prediction.  But you anyone know what kind of prediction is that? it seems like KNN prediction but didnt use the K for calculate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the way mean user ratings are calculated in the prediction function.

Calling mean on the ratings array includes all the 0 values which represents movies not rated by the user.

You will want to create the array of ratings by performing the mean function only on the ratings rated by the user. This can be performed by a simple groupby operation on the train data

```
mean_user_rating = train_data.groupby('user_id')['rating'].mean()
```